# Editing immutable state items

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to update some immutable data. However, I am doing it incorrectly and it doesn't work.

My understanding, is I need to pass it a unique it (eg the `key`) so it knows which item in state to update. But this may be wrong, and I would like to do this the proper way. I tried the immutability helper, but had no success.

I will also want to update/add/remove nested items in an immutable array.

I put this in a codeSandbox for ease https://codesandbox.io/s/mz5WnOXn

```
class App extends React.Component {
  ...
  editTitle = (e,changeKey) => {
   this.setState({
    movies: update(this.state.movies, {changeKey: {name: {$set: e.target.value}}})
  })
    console.log('Edit title ran on', key)
  };

  ...

  render() {
  ...
    return (
      <div>
        {movies.map(e => {
          return (
            <div>
              <input key={e.pk} onChange={this.editTitle} value={e.name} changeKey={e.pk} type="text" />
              With genres:
              {e.genres.map(x => {
                return (
                  <span key={x.pk}>
                    <input onChange={this.editGenres} value={x.name} changeKey={x.pk} type="text" />
                  </span>
                );
              })}
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Index is what `update` needs in order to know which data to change.

Firstly, map sure your map is creating an index:

```
{movies.map((e,index) => {
return (
            <input key={e.pk} onChange={e => this.editTitle(e, index)} value={e.name} >
...
```

Then pass the index to the immutability-helper `update` like so:
to:

```
  editTitle = (e, index) => {
   this.setState({
    movies: update(this.state.movies, {[index]: {name: {$set: e.target.value}}})
  })
```

Answer (score 1):

Couple of things,
1. By looking at your data i don't see any `pk` property maybe its a typo (are you trying to use the `id` property instead?).
2. The `key` prop should be on the root element that you return on each iteration of your `map` function.
3. You can't just add none native attributes to a native Html element instead you can use the `data-*` like `data-changeKey` and access it via `e.target.getAttribute('data-changeKey')`

Something like this:

```
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import React from 'react';
import { reject, pluck, prop, pipe, filter, flatten, uniqBy } from 'ramda';
import { smallData } from './components/data.js';
import './index.css';
import Result from './components/Result';
import update from 'react-addons-update';

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      movies: smallData.movies,
      selectedFilters: {},
      searchQuery: '',
    };
  }
  editTitle = (e) => {
    const attr = e.target.getAttribute('data-changeKey');
    this.setState({
      movies: update(this.state.movies, {
        // what are you trying to do here?
        //changeKey: { name: { $set: e.target.value } },
      }),
    });
    console.log('edit title ran on', attr);
  };

  onSearch = e => {
    this.setState({
      searchQuery: e.target.value,
    });
  };

  render() {
    const { movies } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        {movies.map((e, i) => {
          return (
            <div key={i}>
              <input
                onChange={this.editTitle}
                value={e.name}
                data-changeKey={e.id}
                type="text"
              />
              With genres:
              {e.genres.map((x,y) => {
                return (
                  <span key={y}>
                    <input
                      onChange={this.editTitle}
                      value={x.name}
                      data-changeKey={x.id}
                      type="text"
                    />
                  </span>
                );
              })}
              Add new genre:
              <input type="text" />
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: Thanks. Correct, PK wasn't the isn't my data. I found out that i can use `index` instead, and provided an answer above. Not sure which one is more better